# Does Ruby support type-hinting?

Tags: ruby, type-hinting

PHP Example:

```
function do_something(int $i) {
    return $i + 2;
}
```

Ruby Example:

```
class MyClass
    # ...
end

def do_something(MyClass x)
    x.prop1 = "String..."
end
```

Is there anything similar to this?  Thanks.

Comment: note that php supports typehinting for arrays and objects only. `(int $i)` is unfortunately not possible. Btw why the downvotes here? For me, as a PHP-dev, this is interesting

Comment: Sorry what? PHP does not support scalar typehinting without 3rd party extensions

Comment: @Hast unfortunately not

Comment: That's perfectly valid syntax: [it just doesn't do what you think it does](http://3v4l.org/3M9LQ)

Comment: Ruby itself *doesn't* support type-hinting, but that's not to say there isn't an extension or tooling that does .. I think this is a good question, because even Python has RPython which is a restricted form along the same lines. Also, other dynamic languages like Clojure and AS support type-hinting, so it is doable. It's nice to see thinking Outside the Duck.

Comment: @ircmaxell nice :) I had expected one cannot use the reserved word `int` as a class name in php.. but at least if you try the following it will get weird: http://3v4l.org/e69WO ;) Btw, you are a php-dev... why not inventing something like `__toInt()` in addition to `__toString()`?.. Then I would use `SplInt` class

Comment: Removed the tag/title reference to PHP. It isn't really relevant how language X does (or doesn't) do it in this case.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I've got a proposal sleeping for that: [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object_cast_to_types)...

Comment: Just wanted to add (as I randomly stumbled upon this thread): PHP7 added scala typehinting as well. Typehinting is something I hardly miss in ruby. But ok, at least there is Scala...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby does not have such thing, but all you have to do is add a single line as so:

```
def do_something(x)
  raise "Argument error blah blah" unless x.kind_of?(MyClass)
  ...
end
```

Not a big deal. But if you feel it is too verbose, then just define a method:

```
module Kernel
  def verify klass, arg
    raise "Argument error blah blah" unless arg.kind_of?(klass)
  end
end
```

and put that in the first line:

```
def do_something(x)
  verify(MyClass, x)
  ...
end
```

Comment: For documentation such as yard, rdoc, there is a special syntax to specify the class of the arguments.

Comment: Aside from the aesthetic concerns, this is not semantically equivalent to type hinting. Crucially, this is _runtime_ checking, compared to type hinting, which allows _static_ checking. I.e. I can check all code paths immediately, without having to run them. I'm not trying to trash Ruby, just pointing out runtime type checks aren't equivalent. This is only equivalent with full test coverage (beyond just "100% coverage": it must test every codepath, which is more than just hitting every syntactic line). that's... quite a "big deal" :P

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 3 will introduce types to Ruby ([Source](https://twitter.com/darkdimius/status/1119115657776209920)). You can already use [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) now to add types to your ruby code.

Answer (score 5):

Shameless plug - I just published a ruby gem for this - http://rubygems.org/gems/type_hinting

Usage is here - https://github.com/beezee/ruby_type_hinting

I went looking for it first and found this thread. Couldn't find what I was looking for so I wrote it and figured I'd share here.

I think it's more concise than any of the proposed solutions here and also allows you to specify return type for a method.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to make sure a certain action is performed on an instance of a specific class (like an integer), then consider defining that action on the specific class:

```
class Integer
  def two_more
    self + 2
  end
end

3.two_more   #=> 5
2.0.two_more #=> undefined method `two_more' for 2.0:Float (NoMethodError)

class MyClass
  def do_something
     self.prop1 = "String..."
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like a guarantee for name collisions and side effects and not usable if multiple arguments are needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, Ruby itself doesn't support it, and I think that isn't the intention of Matz to add it to the language... Ruby really embraces [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in its own internal API and it makes Ruby a very dynamic and productive language...

Comment: That's all well and good until you get to complex systems and said arguments need to match a certain implementation. Ruby, as great a language as it is - could really do with such a feature. It's a great feature of some of the best OO languages :)