# How to make Ruby methods show what types they expect

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

What is the best practice for expressing intent with Ruby method names?

For example, with the following:

```
class Formula
  attr_accessor :steps

  def find_step(key)
    @steps.find {|s| s.name == key }
  end

end
```

and:

```
class Step
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

The `Formula#find_step` method expects a `Symbol` but it could just as easily take a `Step` type and check that the names match. I could rename the method `find_step_by_name` but it's still not clear what `name` is. Is it a string or a symbol? Or is it matching the name on a `Step` object?

Edit: marked as a possible duplicate of [Does Ruby support type-hinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685712/does-ruby-support-type-hinting)
I'm not asking if it's possible, I'm asking a question about naming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ruby support type-hinting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685712/does-ruby-support-type-hinting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after Ruby2.1 I think the following solution is nice.

```
def find_by(name:)
  # and you can check if type of name is what you expect as you need.
  # But that is not duck-typingy.
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of Ruby's required keyword arguments until now. The way you have `find_by` defined raised an error for missing keyword: name.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to raise an exception. The empty keyword in the method argument list is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that `find_step_by_name` makes it clear that is expects a `name` and not a `step` that might have a name. If you are unsure if to support strings or symbols then allow both:

```
  def find_step_by_name(name)
    @steps.find { |s| s.name == name.to_s }
  end
```

Comment: This matches Rails' convention of `find_by_name` for finding by the `name` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I marked this correct just before seeing Huang Minghe's answer. I like the required keyword arguments even better because it makes for a more concise method name and it raises an error if a required keyword is missing. You can also have optional keywords. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer to the question is good choice of the argument name. If you intend a symbol to be passed into your find_by method, why not do this:

```
def find_by(symbol)
  @steps.find {|s| s.name == symbol }
end
```

However, I think this would be clearest option:

```
def find_by_name(symbol)
  @steps.find {|s| s.name == symbol }
end
```

I don't agree that using a keyword solves this problem. All it does is change the way the string or symbol is passed into the method.

```
def find_by(name:)
  puts name
end

find_by name: 'this'  # name has to be passed in via hash
find_by name: :that

def find_by(name)
  puts name
end

find_by 'this' # name is passed in directly
find_by :that
```

It doesn't get over the problem that 'name' doesn't imply what type of object is being passed in.

I think keywords are really useful if you are passing in multiple arguments into the method, as they makes the code much more readable at the point it is used.

```
def mass(width:, height:, density:)
  width * height * density
end

mass width: 3, height: 11, density: 0.5
```

That means you don't have to go to the mass method definition each time it's used to work out what's being passed in. It also removes the necessity to get the argument order correct. This will work just as well:

```
mass width: 3, density: 0.5, height: 11
```

But for a method that has a single argument, I think you're just adding complexity by using keywords.

Comment: I think @spickerman rightly points out that this method shouldn't care whether it's passed a string or a symbol. With duck typing our method can be even more flexible (e.g. add a .to_s method to Step). But overall I prefer to have a shorter method name with self-documenting argument list. Your find_by(symbol) isn't clear what symbol it's looking for without looking into the method definition.

Comment: I agree. In the vast majority of cases, the argument type should be irrelevant, and I wouldn't use this style of parameter naming. But in the small number of cases where type is important, I think this is the clearest way of doing it.